# How can I save Task Scheduler column widths in Windows 7 and 8.1?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, task-scheduler, mmc

In Windows 7 and 8.1, I can create custom consoles using Microsoft Management Console (MMC), and they can include view settings like the position of dividers, column widths, etc. This works for most of the console snap-ins, but not for Task Scheduler.

I can create a custom Task Scheduler console with MMC, but not all of the view settings are saved.

I've tried with various combinations of the options `Console mode`, `Do not save changes to this console`, and `Allow the user to customize views`, with only limited success. For example, I found that in the task list, changes to the width of the **Name** column are saved, but changes to the width of the **Triggers** column are not.

I'm currently testing this with a custom console containing only the Task Scheduler snap-in. It's in 'Author' mode, which means that I'm always prompted to save changes when I close it, which confuses things a bit. I find it helpful to always save immediately after opening it; that way any changes I make that are actually detected by MMC cause the **Save** prompt to appear. Regardless, not all changes are actually saved. For example, if I add or remove a column, or rearrange the columns, those changes are saved. Most column width changes are not saved.

I want to do this because otherwise, whenever I open the Task Scheduler console, the first thing I do is adjust column widths, for which the defaults are not useful.

Comment: I created an MMC with a Task Scheduler snap-in. The tree explorer on the left remembers my settings, also the window size, but the right does not and neither column widths of snap-ins. Also the Prompt always comes up for me, even if no changes are made.

Comment: @mt025: About the prompt: you're absolutely correct: in Author mode it always comes up when closing, even if no changes are made. I'll adjust my question.